# function basehaz in cox model using the counting process data structure

Tags: survival

I'm fitting a Cox model two-ways: once with each unit on each line and obtain a baseline hazard output via the function "basehaz". If I fit the model to the same data but in counting process structure I get some output from basehaz that does not seem to make sense.  Is this function not supposed to be used for counting process data structure, or do I need to specify something in the function ? See example below

Initial data

```
  id time death age female
1  1    1     1  20      0
2  2    4     0  21      1
3  3    7     1  19      0
4  4   10     1  22      1
5  5   12     0  20      0
6  6   13     1  24      1

basehaz(model.1s, centered=TRUE)

      hazard time   strata
1  0.0879920    1 female=0
2  0.2010077    7 female=0
3  0.2010077   12 female=0
4  0.0000000    4 female=1
5  2.1731423   10 female=1
6 18.1065842   13 female=1
```

Now same data in counting process form

```
   id age female time0 time1 death
1   1  20      0     0     1     1
2   2  21      1     0     1     0
8   2  21      1     1     4     0
3   3  19      0     0     1     0
9   3  19      0     1     7     1
4   4  22      1     0     1     0
10  4  22      1     1     7     0
16  4  22      1     7    10     1
5   5  20      0     0     1     0
11  5  20      0     1     7     0
17  5  20      0     7    10     0
23  5  20      0    10    12     0
6   6  24      1     0     1     0
12  6  24      1     1     7     0
18  6  24      1     7    10     0
24  6  24      1    10    13     1

basehaz(model.2s, centered=TRUE)

       hazard time   strata
1  0.06225217    1 female=0
2  0.14220801    7 female=0
3  0.14220801   10 female=0
4  0.14220801   12 female=0
5  0.00000000    1 female=1
6  0.00000000    4 female=1
7  0.00000000    7 female=1
8  1.53744454   10 female=1
9 12.80996162   13 female=1
```